# Split devise edit user registration into 2 separate forms to change email and change password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, devise, simple-form

I've searched topics but this exact question doesn't come up. Is it possible to separate the Devise user form to make it 2 separate forms?

- change email
- change password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to create a simple CRUD, as in any other case. it is also posible to generate the view that devise uses and/or override the controllers.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface

Managing your users is not really devise related, devise only really handles authentication.